# Oracle to DB2 - Migrate

Tags: sql, oracle, function, db2

I have to migrate all procedures from Oracle to DB2 database. I'd like to know, how do i Call function inside of procedure like that one bellow

**Function Script**

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE GPRSG001

AS
    -->> Variáveis <<--
    TYPE v_trLinha  IS RECORD (v_sColuna VARCHAR2(32767));
    TYPE v_ttTabela IS TABLE OF v_trLinha;   

FUNCTION GPRS7004(
            -->> Parâmetros de Entrada <<--
            pe_sTexto VARCHAR2)
        RETURN VARCHAR2;
    END GPRSG001;
```

**Oracle Script**

```
BEGIN
        SELECT CCOOP
          INTO ps_iPkCooperativa
          FROM COOP
         WHERE GPRSG001.GPRS7004(NDOCTO || ICOOP) = v_sParametrosFormatados;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
            THEN ps_iPkCooperativa := 0;
    END;
```

Thks Guy

Comment: You don't need to do anything special if you enable Oracle compatibility in Db2 for LUW. There's an entire [book written about it](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247736.html?Open).

Comment: I try to find something related with proc calling function on that doc that you've sent but didnt find.